# Custom dropdown list from Codrops - reducing width of button

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I'm using this psuedo dropdown list from Codrops (it's actually a UL LI list) and I want to change some styling but I cannot find where the style for the width of the arrow box is anywhere.

See:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index.html

When you click the arrow to see the dropdown box you'll see that there is a "square" of white on the right of the original dropdown box. The bit with the arrow in. I want to make this much narrower (so that it is only the size of the arrow with a tiny bit of padding) but I cannot find the width for this ANYWHERE. It doesn't show up in the computed style, layout or anywhere in the inspector. I don't understand where this width is set and how I can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the white box is being controlled by the gradient on line 109 of style.css:

```
 .wrapper-dropdown-1.active {
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #9BC7DE 0%, #9BC7DE 81%, #FFFFFF 78%, #FFFFFF 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }
```